# Conditional probabilty calculation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have two probabilities:

`P(A) = 0.002` ... The probability that someone has a specific disease

`P(B) = 0.995` ... The probability that the bloodtest for the disease shows the correct result

First of all I want to determine the probability that the bloodtest is positive, I tried it this way:

`P(B|A) + P(B'|A')` ... so I have the probabilty that someone has the disease and the test is correct plus the probabilty that someone does not has the disease, but the test is false positive.

I looked this up at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability but have trouble figuring out how to exactly calculate thouse Conditional probabilities.

I tried it this way:

```
0.002 * 0.995 + 0.998 * 0.005 = 0.00698
```

but I believe that this is not correct.

Furthermore I want to determine the probabilty that when a test is positive this means the person really has the disease.

which to my understanding should be

```
P(A|B)
```

Thank you for any help in advance

Comment: Let A be the event "A person has the disease" and T be the event "The test is positive" then your first information is P(A) = 0.002 but your second should be P(T|A) = 0.995, i.e. the probability the test is positive given that the person has the disease (test gives the correct result). now you need to find P(T)

Comment: No it is statet that the 0.995 are for the event "The test is correct" for people who have the disease and people who do not have the disease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

I think your calculation is OK but not the formula. Let's define event $C = \text{"Test is positive"}$. $C$ can occur in two ways: true positive and false positive, so $C = (A\cap B) \cup (A^{'}\cap B^{'})$.

Then $P(C) = P(A\cap B) + P(A^{'} \cap B^{'}) = P(A)P(B) + P(A^{'})P(B^{'})$ because it is assumed $A$ and $B$ are independent. This gives $P(C) = 0.00698$ as per your calculation.

2.

The probability needed is $P(A\mid C)$, not $P(A\mid B)$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(A\mid C) &=& P(A\cap C) / P(C) \\
&=& P(A\cap ((A\cap B) \cup (A^{'}\cap B^{'})) / P(C) \\
&=& P(A\cap B) / P(C) \\
&=& P(A)P(B) / P(C) \\
&=& 0.002 \times 0.995 / 0.00698 \\
&\approx& 0.285.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain how you come from `P(A∩((A∩B)∪(A′∩B′))` to `P(A∩B)` ?

Comment: @JakobAbfalter Sure. $A\cap((A\cap B)\cup (A'\cap B')) = (A\cap A\cap B)\;\cup\;(A\cap A'\cap B') = (A\cap B)\;\cup\;\varnothing = A\cap B$.